# Unable to set proper height of the list view in android

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with the following elements, in the same sequence listed

1. text view
2. image view
3. switch
4. list view

Now i have fixed sizes for 1, 2 and 3.
I want the list view to  take the rest of the space but not go beyond it.
Currently when the list becomes very long, it goes outside the relative layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="17dip"
    android:paddingRight="17dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/battery_perc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100%"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#BCBDC0"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/battery_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/battery_perc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/battery_perc"
        android:src="@drawable/bat_100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/battery_perc"
        android:gravity="bottom|left"
        android:textColor="#BCBDC0"
        android:text="ALL OK"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/status"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textOff="       "
        android:textOn="       "
        android:thumb="@drawable/plug_thumb_bitmap"
        android:track="@drawable/btntoggle_selector_light" />

    <extView
        android:id="@+id/alerts_switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switch"
        android:text="ALERTS"
        android:textColor="#BCBDC0"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/status" >


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/list_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_progress_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:text="LOADING HISTORICAL DATA ..."
            android:textColor="#BCBDC0"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

could someone please help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you show complete layout ?

Comment: without the full layout we all here will be doing guess work?

Comment: I have posted the full layout. could you please help?

Comment: @Sunny can you provide any snap??

Answer (score 1):

You just add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` into your FrameLayout. Try out this if this not working then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to listview

```
<ListView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

put `ListView` below the `Switch` and set height of ListView to `match_parent`

```
<ListView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/switch"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```